# How to change Groovy Date format

Tags: date, groovy, time, format

I want to get my dates into a format like this:  `2010-10-01`

How do I do this?

Also, I grabbed this from another question:

`use (groovy.time.TimeCategory) {`

```
Date date = Date.parse("dd-MMM-yyyy", "15-Mar-2011")

def months = (0..11).collect { 
    (date + it.months).format("MMM/yyyy") 
}
```

`}`

How would I change the output of this script to the format I specified above?  Thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to parse it out from a String:

```
Date.parse( "yyyy-M-d", "2010-10-01" )
```

In order to format the date that you already have:

```
def yourDate= new GregorianCalendar( 2010, Calendar.OCTOBER, 1 )

assert String.format('%tY-%<tm-%<td', yourDate) == '2010-10-01'
```

#### EDIT (to answer the comment)

```
groovy:000> yourDate= new GregorianCalendar( 2010, Calendar.OCTOBER, 1 )
===> java.util.GregorianCalendar[...]
groovy:000> print String.format('%tY-%<tm-%<td', yourDate)
2010-10-01===> null
groovy:000>
```

and backwards:

```
groovy:000> Date.parse( "yyyy-M-d", String.format('%tY-%<tm-%<td', yourDate) )
===> Fri Oct 01 00:00:00 EDT 2010
```

current date:

```
groovy:000> yourDate = Calendar.instance
===> java.util.GregorianCalendar[..]
groovy:000> print String.format('%tY-%<tm-%<td', yourDate) 
2011-11-03===> null
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm close.  Printing `yourdate` spits out a very long string, which I assume is the output of `GregorianCalendar`.  How do I get a variable out of this that only has the date as a value, in the format I want?  i.e. I want `yourdate` to print as `2010-10-01`

Comment: that is how it prints ( try print String.format('%tY-%<tm-%<td', yourDate) ), I added an example

Comment: I want to use `yourDate` in the script shown in the question.  I want to be able to do : `yourDate + it.months`

Comment: Also, what if I want `yourDate` to be the current date, in the same format `yyyy-mm-dd`?

Comment: One final question - Calendar.instance returns 2011-11-03.  How would I make it always return "01" in the "days" value?  i.e. `01` instead of `03`

Comment: yourDate.set( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1 )

Comment: Well that pretty much does it.  I wish you happiness and success.

Answer (score 0):

This also works now:

```
def yourDate = new GregorianCalendar( 2010, Calendar.OCTOBER, 1 )
assert yourDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd') == '2010-10-01'
```